# Playwright & Chrome: "This browser or app may not be secure"

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to test in Chrome so I can run Google Lighthouse directly in my test suite.
When I try to login I get a page from Google saying "The browser or app may not be secure"
after I submit my email address.

I've seen a few other posts with this issue and tried their suggestions but I can't seem to work around it, can't anybody help?

This is how I set up my browser in playwright.config.ts

```
{
  name: 'Chrome - Desktop',
  use: {
    ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
    browserType: 'chromium',
    launchOptions: {
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    },
    chromium: {
      args: ['--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'],
    },
  } as LaunchOptions,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that you are proceeding on a safe site after sharing your email you can simply disable them by adding them in args.

here are some of the args you can use to disable the errors you are facing

```js
      args = [
        "--disable-notifications",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--deterministic-fetch",
        "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process",
        "--disable-site-isolation-trials",
        "--disable-web-security",
    ];
```

you can read more here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/main/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a bunch of arguments but I still can't anything apart from the "may not be secure" page

Comment: can you share some screenshot for same?

Comment: Screenshots of what? The browser? https://imgur.com/a/urgra2v